# How do I use PGP with Thunderbird in 16.04?

Tags: thunderbird, pgp

I'm an Ubuntu newbie. Can anyone tell me how to set up PGP on Thunderbird today? It looks like it may have changed.

Should I download more of the canonical apps (an option in software setup)?

Comment: See the last paragraph of the accepted answer on the linked question for a more practical approach using the Thunderbird add-on “Enigmail”. The fundamental principle will stay the same and this is pretty much what Enigmail does underneath the hood.

Comment: @DavidFoster The answer you linked to, deals with symmetric encryption which really is not the point of using PGP. I therefore think that the duplicate vote is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

install enigmail plugin for thunderbird
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/enigmail/

It's OpenPGP extension for Thunderbird. Enigmail allows users to access the features provided by the popular GnuPG software from within Thunderbird.